# What are garden ornaments?

Tags: snoopys-street-fair

In Snoopy's Street Fair, there is a quest where you have to obtain 4 garden ornaments.

What counts as a garden ornament? I apparently have 1 (the quest is 25% complete), but I have a lot of scenery objects, so I am not sure which one it is.

I know that it isn't lawnmowers or tricycles or the chessboard table, seeing as I have bought a few of these items with no change in the quest completion.

I am also hoping that I will be able to finish this quest without buying any Snoopy dollars to buy things, as I would rather not spend real world money on this game.

What do I need to finish this quest?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarfs_(Discworld) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_gnome

Answer (score 2):

A bird bath is considered a garden ornament. The trycicle is not concidered as a garden ornament. I suggest you buy 4 bird baths and then just sell them to get your money back.

Answer (score 1):

The bird feeder is one as well. I suspect the potted plants and trees are, but can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

A birdbath is a garden ornament. A lawnmower and a deck chair aren't.

I think it's best to just get 4 birdbaths and sell 3 of them after.

Answer (score 0):

Potted trees and flowers don't count, I tried that. The birdbath is and I think the pond probably is, but I can't buy it yet since I'm only level 15 but it doesn't cost real money which is sweet.

Answer (score -2):

Birdbath is one of the garden ornaments. You could just buy 4 of them to complete the quest.

Comment: Do you know where you can obtain Birdbaths? Without that information this answer, while helpful, feels incomplete.

Comment: @Caela - while I understand I can just buy birdbaths (and this answers the "what do I have already" part, so that's cool), I am more looking for what else constitutes a garden ornament - looking at other quests, if I needed to just buy 4 birdbaths, it would have said so. I am trying for some variety at my fair, if possible.